# How to select the same tables in multiple schemas dynamically in POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

I have a "catalog" schema in postgres that contains the following table storing the company name and it's schema:

```
companies(id int, name string, schema string)
```

each company has a schema with the same tables.

I want to loop through this table and count all users from each company, like this:

```
select 
c.name,
(count(u.id) from concat(c.schema, '.users') u ) usersCount
from catalog.companies c
```

Obviously this approach is not working, I saw some posts showing how do this with prepared statements but I couldn't adapt them to my use case.

Answer (score -2):

you need to use dynamic SQL in a PL/pgSQL (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) procedure.

to execute dynamic sql, you can EXECUTE cmd (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: Hey there @mshabou, thanks for your reply. Can you be more specific? How do I return the rows? I know that the answer is somewhere in the docs but I couldn't figure it out.